# Are template files in theme /modules folder overritten after update?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

What I know is :

The folder of module views in themes folder is for customizing and overriding the default behaviour of the module views.  (for example `root/themes/my-theme/modules/blockcategories/`)

But I observed that files in this folder contain a disclaimer (the famous one):

```
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
* needs please refer to http://www.prestashop.com for more information.
```

Why they have put this disclaimer also in these files? I already did my best to make all my changes far from the `root/modules/clockcategories/`.

Prestashop version : 1.6.0.6

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

No, the overriding template files will not be overwritten on updates, except if it's theme update. The disclaimer is there probably because the overriding template files was copied and modified from the original module's template.

Answer (score 1):

This is only part of the default theme "default-bootstrap". You should never use the default theme for live site. You must clone it and work on the "clone". This way nothing will be overridden from the theme during the upgrade of PrestaShop or upgrade of specific modules.